# complex regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, url

I have a rather complex (to me it seems rather complex) problem that I'm using regular expressions in Java for:

I can get any text string that must be of the format:

```
M:<some text>:D:<either a url or string>:C:<some more text>:Q:<a number>
```

I started with a regular expression for extracting **the text between the M:/:D:/:C:/:Q:** as:

`String pattern2 = "(M:|:D:|:C:|:Q:.*?)([a-zA-Z_\\.0-9]+)";`

And that works fine if the `<either a url or string>` is just an alphanumeric string.  But it all falls apart when the embedded string is a url of the format:

tcp://someurl.something:port

Can anyone help me adjust the above reg exp to extract the text **after :D: to be either a url or a alpha-numeric string**?

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "M:myString1:D:tcp://someurl.com:8989:C:myString2:Q:1";
    boolean matchFound = false;
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    String pattern2 = "(M:|:D:|:C:|:Q:.*?)([a-zA-Z_\\.0-9]+)";
    Matcher m3 = Pattern.compile(pattern2).matcher(name);

    while (m3.find()) {
        matchFound = true;
        String m = m3.group(2);
        System.out.println("regex found match:  " + m);
        values.add(m);
    }

}
```

In the above example, my results would be:

```
myString1
tcp://someurl.com:8989
myString2
1
```

And note that the Strings can be of variable length, alphanumeric, but allowing some characters (such as the url format with :// and/or . - characters

Comment: Can you please show expected output for the given input? It isn't clear what you are trying to extract. Multiple variations to illustrate would help.

Comment: Add some example cases and the desired result of that sample, it would be better to understand what you want.

Comment: Just as a side note I suggest using a visualizer such as https://www.debuggex.com/ (pcre  option). I'll post my solution later but I suggest breaking it up into different parts and putting it together progmatically

Comment: (M:|:D:|:C:|:Q:)(((https?|tcp):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?(:[0-9]{1,5})?|[a-zA-Z_\\.0-9 ]+) this will match what you want quickly the way you where using your original regex. But it's not the best way in my opinion. Like Aarjav said, if you break it up in parts, it would be better.

Comment: I've updated the original post.  Whoever -1'd me - I don't think that was necessary.  If you actually read the regex and the expected format of the string, that should be enough to suggest a solution for extracting whatever text is between the constants.  I'm going to try @Shar1er80 's solution, that looks about right - I think he or she is right:  regex probably just complicates the solution unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that the format is constant:

```
M:<some text>:D:<either a url or string>:C:<some more text>:Q:<a number>
```

Capture groups can do this for you with the pattern:

```
"M:(.*):D:(.*):C:(.*):Q:(.*)"
```

Or you can do a `String.split()` with a pattern of `"M:|:D:|:C:|:Q:"`.  However, the split will return an empty element at the first index.  Everything else will follow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Regex: ");
    String data = "M:<some text>:D:tcp://someurl.something:port:C:<some more text>:Q:<a number>";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("M:(.*):D:(.*):C:(.*):Q:(.*)").matcher(data);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("String.split(): ");
    String[] pieces = data.split("M:|:D:|:C:|:Q:");
    for (String piece : pieces) {
        System.out.println(piece);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Regex: 
<some text>
tcp://someurl.something:port
<some more text>
<a number>

String.split(): 

<some text>
tcp://someurl.something:port
<some more text>
<a number>
```

Comment: The first solution is best for when validation isn't needed (you may want to use `.+` instead of `.*` though). For the second solution, although rare, it is possible for the url to contain sequences such as `M:` which would lead to invalid results. you can just length of the returned array to make sure that there weren't extra splits.

Comment: Thank you @Shar1er80 - your solution was the simplest and works like charm !  I went with the first solution and apply validations after extracting the text between the constant separators.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the URL/text part you don't need the regular expression. Use

```
int startPos = input.indexOf(":D:")+":D:".length();
int endPos = input.indexOf(":C:", startPos);
String urlOrText = input.substring(startPos, endPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to do some validation along with the parsing:

break the regex into different parts like this:

```
    String m_regex = "[\\w.]+"; //in jsva a . in [] is just a plain dot
    String url_regex = ".";     //theres a bunch online, pick your favorite.
    String d_regex = "(?:" + url_regex + "|\\p{Alnum}+)"; // url or a sequence of alphanumeric characters
    String c_regex = "[\\w.]+"; //but i'm assuming you want this to be a bit more strictive. not sure.
    String q_regex = "\\d+";    //what sort of number exactly? assuming any string of digits here

    String regex = "M:(?<M>" + m_regex + "):"
                 + "D:(?<D>" + d_regex + "):"
                 + "C:(?<D>" + c_regex + "):"
                 + "Q:(?<D>" + q_regex + ")";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Might be a good idea to keep the pattern as a static field somewhere and compile it in a static block so that the temporary regex strings don't overcrowd some class with basically useless fields.

Then you can retrieve each part by its name:

```
    Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
    if (m.matches()) {
        String m_part = m.group( "M" );
        ...
        String q_part = m.group( "Q" );
    }
```

You can go even a step further by making a RegexGroup interface/objects where each implementing object represents a part of the regex which has a name and the actual regex. Though you definitely lose the simplicity makes it harder to understand it with a quick glance. (I wouldn't do this, just pointing out its possible and has its own benefits)